# Manually crop and save image from Picturebox in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, picturebox

i am having 1 picturebox in winform using C#, i want to crop some part of image and save that selected part it into image.
  Following is my code for croping source image

[image]

```
private void picFace_mousedown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        this.picFace.Invalidate();
    }

private void picFace_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
        }
        this.picFace.Invalidate();
    }

private void picFace_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        using (System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What problem or error are you facing? Currently this is not a question.

Comment: I dont know how to achieve x,y coordinates from picturebox and save this crop image?????i just achieve this image selection part using rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Bitmap has a clone method takes the rectangle you have defined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx

Then when you have your new bitmap, it comes with a save method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx